# Installing Blender - Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXGenGlsl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1.38.6`

Tags: blender, extract

I am trying to install the latest version of Blender `3.5.1` however I am getting errors that the following is not in my system. I have tried to get the dependencies, but its weird that even just extracting the files isn't allowed.

```
(base) hutber@hutber:/mnt/nas/Downloads$ tar -xf blender-3.5.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXGenGlsl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXGenGlsl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1.38.6’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXFormat.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXFormat.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1.38.6’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXGenMdl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXGenMdl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXGenGlsl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXGenGlsl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXFormat.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXFormat.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXGenShader.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXGenShader.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1.38.6’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXGenShader.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXGenShader.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXGenOsl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXGenOsl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXCore.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXCore.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1.38.6’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXGenMdl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXGenMdl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1.38.6’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXCore.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXCore.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1’: Operation not supported
tar: blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MaterialX/PyMaterialXGenOsl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1: Cannot create symlink to ‘PyMaterialXGenOsl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.1.38.6’: Operation not supported
```